# React Conditional rendering is not re-rendering to toggle between two icons, "onClick not working as I want it to"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, conditional-rendering

### Goal

I am building a Pomodoro clock using react.js, the idea is to use a **single start/pause button(an icon)** to start/stop the session timer.

---

### Problems facing

1. The setInterval method **starts another timer** (with the previous countdown still playing) when I complete a play -> pause -> play cycle

> demonstrated in gif below

2. **The icon won't change from the 'stop' to 'play'** but the **value of the flag(isPaused) is updated**
   (My not so deep Websearch suggests that **render only renders once** and I need to use UseEffect or something. (please guide me on how can I re-render a react-fonts tag defined using a conditional render every time I click that button (icon)

---

Here is the UI

[image: APP UI]

---

Here is the render

[image: 1st click functions as I want, 2nd click behaves weirdly(for me at least)]

I don't understand why setInterval triggers another countdown (fun fact: I can trigger unlimited counters, all displaying in that display, overlapping each other)

---

### Code

1. isPaused is a flag used to pause the setInterval, that I defined as **a global variable**
2. isPaused is also used to check the condition for rendering

`var isPaused = false;`

iconRender is defined inside of **Render**

It is supposed to toggle between play and stop icon, change the flag value(isPaused) and play/pause the countdown

```
    const iconRender = () => {
      if (isPaused === false){
        return <TiMediaPlay onClick={this.timer} className="controls" id="start_stop"/>;
      }
      else if (isPaused === true){
        return <TiMediaStop onClick={this.timer} className="controls" id="start_stop"/>;
      }
    }
```

timer is a function triggered **onClick** that houses setInterval method

```
timer() {
    isPaused ? isPaused = false : isPaused = true
    
    let duration, minutes, seconds;
    duration = this.state.session * 60;
    
    var sessionrun = setInterval(() => {
      if (isPaused) {
        duration -= 1;
        minutes = Math.floor((duration) / 60);
        seconds = duration % 60;
        this.setState({
          timeleft : seconds.toString().length === 1 ? minutes + ':0' + seconds : minutes + ':' + seconds
        })
        if (duration === 0){
          clearInterval(sessionrun);
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
    console.log('value of isPaused : '+ isPaused)
    
  }
```

---

### Complete JS code

[code stored as a google docs file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yLwH8U6VzZh6Sb280ISR39oGdJOkBJDApUzm9ozD-4s/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: try adding `isPaused` to component's state (next to `timeleft`). it's similar to variable but accessed as `this.state.isPaused`, updated with `this.setState()` and React automatically updates UI if it changes. it should resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it did solve the problem of updating the icon on click but how do I stop setInterval from triggering an additional countdown? I'll try to add a condition before declaring the setInterval method.

Comment: Try replacing `setInterval` with `setTimeout` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69155258/14596856). They are almost identical but `setTimeout` has a condition check during every run.